# How to sort environment variables in python

Tags: python

I am printing environment variables, but there are not printed in a sorted way :

```
    for variable in os.environ:
        print("   " + variable + "=" + os.environ.get(variable))
```

I would like to sort os.environ.  I tried to put os.environ in a list(), but the sort function is not working.

Any clue?

Thank you

Comment: "The sort function is not working".  "Not working" is not a problem description.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Show how you "tried to put os.environ in a list".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for name, value in sorted(os.environ.items()):
    print("   " + name + "=" + value)
```

Comment: @peterphonic Using ``'\n'.join( )`` as in my answer displays the result instantly, while repeating prints is longer

Answer (score 3):

```
print '\n'.join("   %-24s=  %s" % x for x in sorted(os.environ.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from json import dumps
from os import environ

print(dumps({k: v for k, v in sorted(environ.items())}, indent=2))
```